# Why do I get this error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m making a program where if a user enters text it will convert any caps into lowercase:

```
def lowerChar(char):
   if ord(char) >= 65 and ord(char) <= 90:
      char = int(ord(char)) + 32
      char = (chr(char))
      return print(char)
   else:
      return print(char)

def lowerString(string):
   x = len(string) 
   for i in range(x):
       char = string[0 + i]
       lowerChar(char)
       result = ""
       result = result + lowerChar(string[i])  

string = input("type")
lowerString(string)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\njn.py", line 24, in <module>
    lowerString(string)
  File "C:\Python34\njn.py", line 19, in lowerString
    result = result + lowerChar(string[i])
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is about implementation and belongs on **[Stack Overflow](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** (implementation issues, such as code fixes (ask on Stack Overflow instead))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return print(char)
```

This will first print the value of `char` (as in `print(char)`) and *then* try to return the return value of the print function. But since the print function always returns `None`—it only *prints* the value, it does not return it—your function will always return `None` causing the error when trying to concatenate `None` with a string.

To fix this, simply don’t print the character but just return it:

```
return char
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're returning the result of the `print` function, which is None.

Instead of:

```
return print(char)
```

You should use simply:

```
return char
```

You probably want to add a `print(result)` to the end of your `lowerString` function too, otherwise you won't have any output.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do `string_variable.lower()` or `'test string'.lower()` since everything is an object in python, the string object has multiple methods attached to it.

```
string = input("type").lower()
print (string)
# or
string = input("type")
string = string.lower()
print (string)
```